# Compiling external kernel module with a lot of source files

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel

I'm newbie to Linux kernel.

When compiling kernel module, I encouter the following problem:

```
make[3]: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
```

Tracking the problem down, I see the problem is when linking (**ld**) the module. 
My module consists of a lot of files, while module sources reside under path of 60 chars length. I see that **ld** uses absolute path to object files.

I'm not too familiar with my build system, but as far as I see we add to **obj-m** *.c files with relative path.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what this is about but if the problem is that the path is too long, one solution is to make a symlink and use that instead.

Comment: Is it possible to change the build to make smaller static libraries, and then link those together to form the module?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg is it possible with kbuild?

Comment: @Pithikos symlink doesn't help too - I see ld still uses absolute paths.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite strange that your kernel module is so big and made of so many files. Conventional wisdom is to have small kernel modules (perhaps communicating with external user-space helper programs). Are you sure of your software architecture design?

Back to the question, you can put all the arguments to `gcc` in a file like `my.args` and just invoke `gcc` with `gcc @my.args` because `gcc` handle `@` specifically.

You can also recompile your kernel, and increase the `#define` for `ARG_MAX` in file `include/linux/limits.h` appropriately. I often define it as 2 mega (bytes) ie `(2<<20)`

Comment: gcc @my.args supported by kbuild files?

Comment: It is a feature of `gcc` itself, not of the build system.

Comment: Nice feature, but I need a solution for kbuild. I'm afraid increasing ARG_MAX is not an option.